# How can I replace a newline with its escape sequence?

Tags: sed, awk

Using `sed` to make text that contains certain characters suitable for use in string literals is straightforward:

```
sed "s/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/g"
sed "s/\\\"/\\\\\\\"/g"
```

But how can I do something similar with a text file containing newline characters?

Comment: sed won't show you the new line character in the find portion, sed is old too,  like a legacy program. You could use perl, it has equivalents to sed's find and replace.

Answer (score 20):

If you're dealing with a pipelined command, then I like [@vossad01's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1296229/266070). However, in a multi-line script, I prefer normal Bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), which is both more efficient (doesn't need to fork a new process for `sed` or create any pipes) and *perhaps* a bit easier to read:

```
${varName//$'\n'/\\n}
```

Reader's guide:

- `${...}` - Interpret the internal stuff using parameter expansion
- `varName` - Name of the variable containing the content
- `//` - Replace all instances of...
- `$'\n'` - The literal newline character (we're turning the escape *into* the literal here)
- `/` - Replace with...
- `\\n` - The newline escape sequence (`"\n"`): note that we had to escape the backslash itself

Example:

```bash
$ foo="$(printf '%s\n' $(seq 1 3))"
$ echo "$foo"
1
2
3
$ echo "${foo//$'\n'/\\n}"
1\n2\n3
```

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'
```

Which uses the answer from [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/1072626) substituting an escaped newline character as the replacement to match the question here.

Comment: This command appears to ignore the last linefeed, and insert an extra unescaped linefeed for those files that do not have a linefeed at the end of the line.

Comment: This works in reverse also if you want to change escaped newlines to actual newlines. Just `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\\n/\n/g'`

Comment: For anyone else wondering what this command is doing: sed can not only replace by regex with `s`, but also do other stuff like here: `:a` declares a label, `N` appends the next input line to the pattern space, and `$!` (if not EOF), `ba` branch/jump back to the label `a`, so this is a loop adding all lines to the context and then newlines can be replaced. Otherwise sed would take line by line and not replace any newline because there is none within the single line.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this one with:

```
sed 's/$/\\n/g' | tr -d'\n'
```

sed puts '\\n' at the end of every line, then tr removes the newlines.

Comment: Nice! Of all the solutions here, this one is easiest to understand and the most straightforward IMO.

Answer (score 2):

sed is line based, and this can cause issues when trying to replace newline characters.

the official documentation for sed makes a specific reference to newline characters and states they are stripped off before being passed to sed.

I would suggest that 'tr' would probably be a better fit here.

as an example, to replace newline characters with spaces:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < inputfile
```

Comment: Won't `[\r\n]` be cleaner?

Comment: I guess that all depends on the source data and requirements. OP only referred to newline. I would recommend to try both and see which produces the best result. YMMV.

Comment: I tried using `tr "\n" "\\n"` before I posted this question and it just replaced the newline characters with backslashes. It seems to only turn a sequence into one character only.

Comment: @Melab correct. the 'tr' command will only do a single character replacement.

Comment: So then how does it help at all?

Comment: @Melab a '\n' character is a single character.   So no problem there. I think perhaps what  you are trying to get at is that tr will only replace with one character. And then you have a point, how will this help at all!

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` solution worked for me:

```
$ awk 1 ORS='\\n' file.txt
```

Credit goes to [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697604/621690).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to extend [David Moytan](https://superuser.com/users/477209/david-moylan)'s solution:

```
cat /etc/passwd | perl -e 'while(<>) { $_ =~ s/[\r\n]/__NEWLINE__/g; print "$_" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.

You can use the \a function to start every newline with the proper escape sequence, then pipe the resulting function into echo -n which suppresses newlines.

```
echo -n $(sed '\a
\\n');
```

Stick whatever you're sed-ing in the parentheses before the sed command.